# Delegates with specific arguments

Tags: c#, class, delegates

I'll try to keep it as simple as I can. I have a delegate `DEL` which is a `void()` (no arguments). I have a function `FUNC(int)`. I have two variables A and B. I want to be able to do `A()` and it will run `FUNC(10)`, and be able to do B() and it will run `FUNC(43)`. I know I can have the delegate be `void(int)` but I also have a function `FUNC2(int, int)`. and a variable C that will run `FUNC2(21,6)`. I need A, B and C to all be the same type of variable.

Comment: This all seems a bit abstract. What is it that you're trying to do at a higher level?

Comment: You can declare your variable as type `Delegate` and have it refer to any delegate regardless of signature but that's a bit inelegant and something you should generally avoid, mainly because you still have to know the signature when you invoke the delegate anyway.  I agree with @Enigmativity that more info is in order.

Comment: Basicly, I have a class. And upon certain conditions I want a function to run. What I was hoping to do, is have a delegate in the class named EVENT, which I will run everytime the conditions are met. Again, the functions I want to run are not all the same. They are all void but they each get different types of arguments. The EVENT delegate will not use  any arguments. I want to be able to place the arguments with the decleration of a new class instance

Comment: Might be best if you write code that you would like to use but does not compile and then people can see and understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have this

```
public delegate void DEL();

public class MyClass
{
    public static void FUNC(int value)
    {
    }

    public static void FUNC2(int value1, int value2)
    {
    }
}
```

And you need variables `A`, `B` and `C` to be declared and initialized to some delegate type such that they call `FUNC(10)`, `FUNC(43)` and `FUNC2(21, 6)` respectively when invoked.

The code for `A`

```
DEL A = () => MyClass.FUNC(10);
```

The code for `B`

```
DEL B = () => MyClass.FUNC(43);
```

And, the code for `C`

```
DEL C = () => MyClass.FUNC2(21, 6);
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are all of type `DEL`

You could also express this as:

```
DEL A = new DEL(() => MyClass.FUNC(10));
```

or

```
DEL A = new DEL(CallFUNCWithValue10);

public static void CallFUNCWithValue10()
{
    MyClass.FUNC(10);
}
```

or just

```
DEL A = CallFUNCWithValue10;
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want. but two things: when I declare a class, I need to do it like this `Class c = new Class(() => Func(12,4);`, Is there an easier way of doing so? and second, what does `() => func(12)` mean? I prefer understanding what I use when I use it, and not taking it for granted...

Comment: @RexMan85 not sure what you mean with the first part of that but () => func(12) is a way of declaring an anonymous method that takes no parameters and has an inferred return type (in this case void). In your example, DEL is a delegate type, so you don't really need to specify new DEL for each one, you can directly sign the anonymous (or named) method to that variable and the compiler will figure it out